# Unable to 'vmc login' to api.cloudfoundry.com due to "undefined method `get' for CFoundry::Client

Tags: authentication, cloud-foundry, vmc

Please see gemlist and vmc error below.

#### $gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS

addressable (2.2.8)
cfoundry (0.3.43)
interact (0.4.8)
json_pure (1.6.7)
mime-types (1.19)
multi_json (1.3.6)
rb-readline (0.4.2)
rest-client (1.6.7)
rubygems-update (1.8.24)
rubyzip (0.9.9)
terminal-table (1.4.5)
uuidtools (2.1.3)
vmc (0.3.20)

qa $vmc login
Attempting login to [http://api.cloudfoundry.com]
Email: xxx@gmail.com
Password: **************

Problem with login to 'http://api.cloudfoundry.com', undefined method `get' for #, try again or register for an account.

Comment: Hi, can you tell me what version of vmc you are using? (vmc -v)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I suggest you try updating VMC to the lastest version, 0.3.21. You can do this by simply re-installing using gem;

```
gem install vmc
```

Comment: sudo gem install vmc    
    Fetching: multipart-post-1.1.5.gem (100%)  
    Fetching: cfoundry-0.3.48.gem (100%)  
    Fetching: vmc-0.3.23.gem (100%)  
    Successfully installed multipart-post-1.1.5  
    Successfully installed cfoundry-0.3.48  
    Successfully installed vmc-0.3.23  
    3 gems installed  
     This update solves the problem. Thanks Dan.

Comment: If you could up-vote and accept the answer, that would be great :-)